# AEM JUnit Test with a DAM Asset

Tags: java, junit, aem, dam

I try to test some DAM Assets with a JUnit test in AEM.

At first I copied an existing asset as JSON in a resource file.
Next, I use the ContentLoader to write the JSON file into the simulated repository.

```
final ContentLoader contentLoader = new ContentLoader(this.getResourceResolver());
contentLoader.json("content/assets/testAsset.json", "/content/assets/testAsset");
```

Then, I use the ResourceResolver to resolve the Resource in the destinationPath.

```
Resource assetRecource = resourceResolver.resolve("/content/assets/testAsset");
```

So far so good. 
When I try to adapt the assetRecource to an Asset.class is the result null.

```
Asset asset = assetRecource.adaptTo(Asset.class); // is null
```

In my opinion it's because the missing renditions.

Do someone have an idea how to fix this? 
Maybe with the ContentLoader#binaryResource()?

Comment: I imagine the `testAsset` json has primaryType of `dam:Asset`. You can also try to check the resource that gets resolved has the same resource type.

Answer (score 1):

Check the resourceType for the resource is to be **dam:Asset**.

```
Resource assetRecource = resourceResolver.resolve("/content/assets/testAsset");
DamUtil.isAsset(assetRecource);   // This would be true if the asset is dam:Asset
assetRecource.getResourceType();  // This would return the resourceType of the resource.
```

The possible reason for adaptTo to be null is only if the resource is not adaptable to Asset Class.

Refrences:

1. https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/api/Asset.html
2. http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/adapter/Adaptable.html#adaptTo(java.lang.Class)

Comment: Sadly, it isn't the fault. The resourceType is 'dam:Asset' yet.

Comment: But the DamUtil throws a NoClassDefFoundError with cause ImageReadException.

Comment: @Unkall - isAsset method of DamUtil just check's the resourceType. It should not be throwing NoClassDefFoundError.

It would be nice if you can provide some code that you're actually using and error log.
[NoClassDefFoundError Reference](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below dependency to test the DAM assests:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-imaging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-imaging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-R1534292</version>
        </dependency>
```